# Homebrew formula how to add lib and other files

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I'm on the process of making a Homebrew tap.

My [repo](https://github.com/shinokada/backpack_install) has a bash script, lib directory, and other directories.

When I use the following, only the backpack_install is available in the `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/backpack_install/0.5.0` directory.

```
class BackpackInstall < Formula
  desc "Backpack Installer for macOS/Linux"
  homepage "https://github.com/shinokada/backpack_install"
  url "https://github.com/shinokada/backpack_install/archive/refs/tags/v0.5.0.tar.gz"
  sha256 "83f2b1e193446c6da00c59bbb671d820e33af8a8c7fd89bdd6ddcf3c21d31c3b"
  license "MIT"

  depends_on "composer"
  

  def install
    bin.install 'backpack_install'
  end
end
```

I need other directories as well. How can modify the `def install` so that libraries are available when I use it.